# Question about this line of code in AppSettingsReader

Tags: vb.net

I was reading this example: http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/AppSettingsReader-and-reading-typed-and-nullable-application-settings.aspx and I noticed in this line of code:

```
int failCount = (int) appSettingsReader.GetValue("FailAttemptCount", typeof(int));
```

I don't understand why there is a (int) before appSettingsReader, what it does, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to GetValue is designed to return the result as various possible types, but the declared return value is Object.  So you tell it to return an int, but then you have to cast the result to `int` so you can reference it as such.

Comment: Is this the only situation where this happens? Can this be applied to anywhere else?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The pattern of having a method that can return a specified type is used sometimes; for example when returning values from a database, say.  In general, it requires that a given method be written to accept a specified return type and convert to that type.  Casting, however, is a widely used technique -- any time you have a value that is specified as one type (e.g. Object) but you happen to know it's really another type (e.g. int) you can cast so that you can refer to the object by it's real type.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I never seen a type cast before an object before (if I said that correctly), so was a bit confused. Thanks Jacob for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 1):

it casts the returned object to an int, this makes sure that the object you get back can be assigend to the int variable failCount. This is needed since the return type of GetValue is Object, not int

Comment: So GetValue is an object by default unless otherwise specified?